# what is the difference between Drupal.formatPlural() and Drupal.t()?

Tags: i18n-l10n

what is the difference between :

`Drupal.t(string, arguments, options )` and `Drupal.formatPlural()`

`Drupal.t()` is used in the javascript part to translate the string and it can accept a set of arguments that will translate the string placeholders ex:

```js
var translatedString = Drupal.t('a string about @subject that needs to be translated', {'@subject': 'Javascript in Drupal'});
```

what about Drupal.formatPlural()

Answer (score 3):

Actually after some playing aroud with the code I HAVE FOUND THE ANSWER :

```
formatPlural($count, $singular, $plural, array $args = array(), array $options = array());
```

## code

the **formPlural** function enable us to translate a string in plural or singular format according to the first argument **$count** , a **$singualr** string will display if **$count = 0 or 1** otherwise if **$count > 1** the **$plural** string will be displayed , and in plural string we can get the **$count** value using **@count** , for example in the code bellow  :

- the first **formPlural** function will return $singular  string since
  $count = 1
- the second **formPlural** function will return $plural
  string since $count > 1

```js
var typeVar = 'list';
var singular = Drupal.formatPlural(1, 'I have 1 item', 'I have many @type items', {'@type': typeVar});
$('#translate_singular_item').html(  singular   );


var plural = Drupal.formatPlural(3, 'I have 1 item', 'I have @count @type items', {'@type': typeVar});
$('#translate_plural_item').html(  plural  );
```

## output

[image]

## Back-office Translation

now we can translate both singular and plural string :
[image]

Comment: Yes, with the exception that in English, 0 is written in the plural format (ex: I have 0 items, not: I have 0 item), and Drupal (as of 10.1, current as of today) will use the plural format if no translation table exists and the language code is set to "en".  Source: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21locale.module/function/locale_get_plural/10